# Two connection strings point to same database (read & read/write). How do I maintain the same transaction for both connection strings?

Tags: c#, .net

I am converting a system that had 2 different connection strings both pointing to the same DB. My plan was to start a connection, grab a transaction, and hold the transaction until the control logic fully completes. However sometimes the code is asking for the read connection and sometimes the code wants the write transaction. I know that I need to operate in the same transaction as updates occur in a write connection and then they are queried by a following read transaction.

How can I make sure that they both run in the same transaction?

Comment: your understanding seems a bit off... in how transactions are done. PS adding code... helps buckets. Show how you think a transaction is done.

Comment: A transaction is created from a connection using SqlConnection.getTransaction(). Thus my concern is that by having two different sqlConnections, one for read, and one for write, they'd produce two different transactions where as I need them to both produce the same transaction.

Comment: like i said add your code.....

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't written it yet for this reason. I want to make sure my design is good from the start. If it was me I'd just have a single sql connection per database and I wouldn't have this problem. However I want to stick w/ what they had as much as possible so I'm trying to see how best to make this work.

Comment: Let me think about this some more, maybe I just need to go the single connection route.

What I wanted was what ever connection (read or readwrite) occurred first I'd store that as the connection for the current session and then I could just use that transaction, but really, if there are both read and write transactions occurring in a single session that I'd NEED to use a read write connection and not just the read connection... so that might be what you're getting at.

Comment: single connection route.... is your answer..